# Running a bare-metal hypervisor and VM on the same machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

Is it possible to install a bare-metal hypervisor on a computer and run VMs created using that on the same computer?

what I'm going to achieve is like Installing a VMware workstation on a Microsoft Windows 10 and then Install a Microsoft Windows 7 in it, but this way the CPU and RAM will be used for no reason in the host operation system. I need to install the bare-metal hyper visor on the hardware level and then Install VMs in it, all of them on the same PC.

[Type1 and Type 2 Hypervisors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpzwk.png)

if it's possible please recommend me some suitable programs for this matter and if not please explain why it's not possible. thanks in advance

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/234837/i-want-to-virtualize-my-workstation-tier-1-looking-for-bare-metal-hypervisor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to have a bare-metal hypervisor running, and let one of its VMs have control of the physical screen, mouse, and keyboard of that same system.

- ESX doesn't do this.  The best you can do is probably get to a maintenance shell which is not meant for everyday use.
- Hyper-V does this.
- You might be able to manually set up a Xen-based system to do this, but things like Xenserver, etc. are setup to run like ESX.

As far as why, keep in mind ESX and such are enterprise products.

- IT support/people already remote into servers, therefore they will be remoting into the VMs as well.  No one is typically at a datacenter working from a local console.  Providing a console/display at the local system is not a priority and would only be done if a severe problem arose.
- Businesses are interested in virtualization for the purpose mostly of moving physical systems to VMs - in order to reduce hardware costs.  So ESX and such want to be as thin as possible to keep overhead as low as possible, to support hosting many systems at once.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will go for the Hyper-V server then and I hope I be able to install and use the VM installed in it on the same PC. by the way, is it really cost effective to use virtualization instead of normal computers? well, to virtualize everything using something like VMware products we need a server to use for vSphere, another powerful server to use for vCenter and yet each client need its own display/mouse/keyboard etc. I've been calculating the costs but couldn't figure out how it is cost effective. could you explain a lil bit about it ?

Comment: If you only have a couple of servers, probably not, but if you have many it is.  Our company had separate physical servers at one time for email, software licensing, domain controllers, ERP software, SQL, VPN server, and more, and we were able to move that all to two physical boxes with less power consumption and rackspace used.  We also can spin up or remove servers easily when needed, and disaster recovery is easier since the drives are virtual as well.  It has a lot of benefits.

Comment: Yeah in that case It's probably cost effective or even fail-safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with some limitations using ESXi. What you want is to assign specific hardware of the host to specific VM's for exclusive use. In particular, you will want GPU and USB controller passthrough. The limitations are in that you can't share hardware (with VM's running) and that you can, for example, only pass through certain GPU's via ESXi.

Check out this article for a similar setup and more specifics:
[Multi-headed VMWare Gaming Setup](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multi-headed-VMWare-Gaming-Setup-564/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually the two type are no longer really distinctive these days:

> However, the distinction between these two types is not necessarily
>   clear. Linux's Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM) and FreeBSD's bhyve
>   are kernel modules that effectively convert the host operating system
>   to a type-1 hypervisor. Nevertheless, since Linux distributions and
>   FreeBSD are still general-purpose operating systems, with other
>   applications competing for VM resources, KVM and bhyve can also be
>   categorized as type-2 hypervisors.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor)

This is pretty much the same case for Hyper-V, which is available in the Windows 10 Pro or so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#Architecture

Comment: Thanks for the information, very useful. but I haven't still got the answer. is what I'm trying to do achievable?

Comment: If you mean you want a hypervisor that has a type-1 architecture/performance while you can you use the host for daily usage (instead of just a panel-ish environment for you to manage the VMs), then Hyper-V is your (only) choice in Windows. However it is not available on Home versions of Windows.

Comment: Oh okay, could you please point me to the web page where I can get the Hyper-V bootable file (ISO file maybe?) which as you said is a Hyper-V server which runs as Hypervisor type-1 bare-metal.

Comment: By the way yes that's right, I want to install the type-1 bare-metal hypervisor on a PC (host) and use the same PC to interact and use VMs (guests) installed in it. I have Windows 10 pro.

Comment: I didn't mean Hyper-V server, coz that's probably not what you want. I mean the Hyper-V feature that you can "enable" in Windows Pro. Go to `Program and Features` in Control Panel and click `Turn Windows features on or off` on the left, then look for `Hyper-V`.

Comment: But that's exactly what VMware workstation does. isn't there a Hyper-V server (like vsphere 6) to be bootable and run on the host in hardware level? all I could find was Hyper-V on Windows server 2012, not a standalone Hyper-V version, if at all.

Comment: Well yes: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2012-r2. You haven't been really clear about what you want exactly though. Hyper-V Server 2016 is still in preview, but it's available on the same page.

Comment: Also, architecturally Hyper-V isn't of the same type as VMWare workstation or VirtualBox AFAIK. In other words, the Hyper-V feature on Windows / Windows Server / Hyper-V Server is architeturally the same. It's just Hyper-V Server has everything else cut down, so yeah it saves you some resources, but might lack of certain things (GUI, host that is available for other daily usage...) you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. In fact that's why it is called "bare metal". This type of hypervisor has a tiny resource footprint and direct access to the hardware.
Type 2 runs on a "normal" OS like Windows Server which has the disadvantage of more overhead (from the host OS).
VMWare Workstation (or VirtualBox or QUEMU) would be Type 2. You are looking for VMWare ESXi (or XenServer or ...).

Comment: Yes, I've already worked with VMware ESXI or vSphere but in these products you have to Install the ESXI on one PC and the vSphere client or the Virtual Machine on another PC, I'm looking for a software to run both of them on the same PC.

Comment: Well, that's not true. You install ESXi and this Hypervisor will give a VM running from it their resources like RAM and CPU. You can then use a shared storage to place the VM physically to another location but it will still get RAM, CPU and Network from the ESXi Server it is run from. This also works without shared storage and you can use the internal HDDs from your ESXi.

Comment: I understand, but can all of these be done on the same PC? if you run the ESXI server on the PC then how can you use the VM created in the hypervisor on the same PC? supposing that I've installed ESXI server on my PC and I used another laptop to create a VM in it, now I put the laptop aside and I want to use the VM created in the ESXI server on that PC. how can I do this? like the client and server be the same PC.

Comment: Ok, I see. The Hypervisor has no managing capabilities (hence the low footprint). But your VM has a network interface and can be accessed with RDP, VNC and the like. You could even run a VM and install the vCenter on this VM running from this ESXi.

Comment: Yes but vCenter required too much resources which is not efficient in my case. if I wanted to run 100VMs on a server then vCenter would come in handy but for 1 or 2 VMs vCenter is totally useless. but unfortunately vSphere 6 ues web console instead of client software and in order to run the web console we need the vCenter. so I'm somehow stuck in here.