# Setting up Hyper V with Windows 10 Pro in most efficient way

Tags: hyper-v, windows-installation, window

For a testing environment I want to setup a host computer with Windows 10 Pro and 3 additional Win 10 instance in Hyper V, I do not need to do anything on (main) host computer I want to install windows on it with minimum required resources.

I will be using separate SSDs for each Hyper-V, on these VMs I will be testing some web applications so I also want to install these windows with minimum resources required.

I'm open to suggestions what windows applications/services should I skip and not install
Any other configurations or setup related things that can help.

Comment: Why waste time and energy on this? Simply install Windows, enable Hyper-V, done.

Comment: I'm investing my time to learn best approach, I'm installing 3 windows instance on a core i7 machine its quite slow otherwise.

Comment: Here is a possible approach for you.   ..... https://superuser.com/questions/1053112/running-a-bare-metal-hypervisor-and-vm-on-the-same-machine